# DataTables Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: json, jsonp, datatables

I try to use the DataTables component with data provided by a REST API. Chrome reports the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` on line 2 (see JSON below) when I use server-side data but it works if I use a text file. The setup is:

```js
$('#table_id')
    .dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "http://mylocalhost:8888/_ah/api/realestate/v1/properties/demo",
            //"sAjaxSource": "data.txt",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "items",
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "id"
            }],
            "fnServerData": function (
                sUrl,
                aoData,
                fnCallback,
                oSettings) {
                oSettings.jqXHR = $
                    .ajax({
                        "url": sUrl,
                        "data": aoData,
                        "success": fnCallback,
                        "dataType": "jsonp",
                        "cache": false
                    });
            }
        }

                                            }
```

The JSON returned by the server or in the data.txt file:

```
{
  "iTotalRecords" : 10,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords" : 10,
  "sEcho" : "1",
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "0"
  }, {
    "id" : "1"
  }, {
    "id" : "2"
  }, {
    "id" : "3"
  }, {
    "id" : "4"
  }, {
    "id" : "5"
  }, {
    "id" : "6"
  }, {
    "id" : "7"
  }, {
    "id" : "8"
  }, {
    "id" : "9"
  } ]
}
```

Changing the `sAjaxSource` to `data.txt` works but not when the data comes from the server whereas the data are the same.

Comment: You told jQuery to expect JSONP, which leads jQuery to execute the response as JavaScript. But the data returned is JSON, which is not a valid JavaScript script, hence you get the error. Either return JSONP from your service, or don't configure the Ajax call to expect JSONP if it is not necessary.

Comment: You are correct, I had to use JSONP because of cross domain ajax call. You can answer the question and I'll mark it as accepted.